# One Signal notification not working when app is live on app store

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, push-notification, onesignal

I'm new to IOS development. I developed app with push notification from One signal. It works fine in debug mode with xcode. But it stops working when it is live on the App store. I already added Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production) certificate. Am I missing something else?

Comment: share your  code

Comment: did you figure out the issue ?

Comment: @MitulBhadeshiya It was an issue in my code